# D3 multiline graph with Array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph

I am trying to build a **D3 Multi-line graph** for which I am getting data from `jsonArray` of Object which is coming from my `JAVA` code.

Below is the `JSON` I am getting.

How do I pass this data in D3 for getting a multi line graph with:

- x-axis as `date`
- y-axis as `noOfColumns`, and,
- z-axis as `fileName`  ?

I am trying to build a graph similar to the one below (found [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955)):

[image: example graph]

```
[
{"date":["2017-12-18 13:31:02.0","2017-12-13 16:00:30.0","2017-12-18 13:30:46.0"],"fileName":"Google-1","noOfColumns":[12,22,54]},
{"date":["2017-12-18 13:29:27.0"],"fileName":"Yahoo-1","noOfColumns":[44]}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer myself to help others. I made some modifications in `JSON` structure and changed it to below. Also, I used `Dimple`  over `D3` to make it simple and got the required graph. Below is the code spinet I used

```
[
{"date":"2017-12-18 13:31:02.0","fileName":"Google-1","numberOfColumns":12},
{"date":"2017-12-13 16:00:30.0","fileName":"Google-1","numberOfColumns":22}
]
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/d3/dimple.v2.3.0.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var data=<%=dataforGraphNew%>;
  var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
  var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
  myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 505, 305);
  var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "date");
  x.addOrderRule("date");
  var y = myChart.addCategoryAxis("y","numberOfColumns");
  var s = myChart.addSeries("fileName", dimple.plot.line);
  s.interpolation = "cardinal";
  myChart.addLegend(60, 10, 500, 20, "right");
  myChart.draw();
 </script>
</div>
```

[image]